# "Is / was / has been / had been used" in a statement

Tags: grammar, past-tense, passive-voice, present-perfect, present-tense

I'm confused whether I should use `are` or `were` or `have been` or `had been` in the following statement when describing the use of language in a passage

> In paragraph 6, detailed adjectives `____` used to describe the scenery of the campus.

The thing is, those adjectives on the passage are/were used to describe the campus when the writer wrote them down in the past, so are they still in effect when I'm writing this sentence?

---

To my knowledge, (sorry, correct me if I am wrong)

1. **is used** means it is currently used at present
2. **was used** means it was once used but no longer in effect
3. **has been used** means the action use started in the past and it's still used or not used now
4. **had been used** means the action used started and ended the past (not used now)

At the same time, I've been told to use past tense **when the date or time is specified** and present perfect **when the the time is unclear or not important** Does passive voice break these rules?

I'm not quite sure in this case describing a world's usage in a passage is a present or completed action. I've fit each option into the blank and I've had an conclusion that have been used seems fluid to me, I'm not sure and if so why others are incorrect?

Sorry asking so many questions at a time, any answer will be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: Past Perfect *...adjectives **had been** used to describe...* makes no sense here, because it *requires* a contextually established "narrative reference time" that's ***already in the past***. Such as *I had an argument with the proofreader because detailed adjectives **had been** used to describe [something]*, where the use of those adjectives happened ***before*** the argument (which was itself in the past).

Comment: Hmmmm, I just thought using singular wording in the title would be more common

Comment: FumbleFingers Never thought of it before, thanks!

Comment: I must also say that "**has been used** means the action use started in the past and it's still used or not used now" doesn't make much sense either. In fact, if I say something ***has been used***, that doesn't actually tell us *anything* about whether it's *still* being used (maybe it is, maybe not). All it tells us is that ***the fact of it having been used is currently relevant***. So I can say *Dinosaurs **have ruled** the planet for far longer than humans are ever likely to*, even though it's been a *long* time since the dinosaurs ruled!

Comment: The author uses these or those words: The words are used by him. That is descriptive writing. You are describing what the author does.

Comment: Use the present *are*. This is known as the narrative or literary present. We would write, for example: *In Chapter 12, Melville writes, "It is not down on any map; true places never are."* — even though Melville wrote  *Moby Dick* in 1851.

Comment: It's going to depend on context and details of what is happening. If, for example, you have one part of a document referencing another part of the same document, you want "are used" because they still are used. If you have a document referencing a previous document you probably want "were used" because the author of a previous document did it then.

Comment: 'In paragraph 6, detailed adjectives are used to describe the scenery of the campus' describes the way the adjectives are used in the passage; unless the article / etc has not survived, this is similar to saying 'there's an ink-blot on my copy of this passage'. See @Tinfoil Hat's explanation.

Comment: Wow thank you for all these lovely replies, I will look into these.

Comment: So, In general I should use present tense becuase I'm writing as the narrator and it's narrative present / descriptive writing that I'm using, so unless the passage is destroyed, I will be using "are" in the sentence?